# NServiceBus 4 with Windows 8 and Azure WebRole Issue

Tags: azure, nservicebus

Running a webrole that is using NServiceBus 4 hangs when running in the local emulator. I have duplicated this on several windows 8 machines. Works fine on Windows 7. It appears that the only way to get it to run is to change the azure project (web settings) to "Use IIS Web Server."  I am running Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012 and Azure 2.0 SDK.

Here is how you can duplicate the problem by working with the PubSub sample from here:
http://particular.net/articles/windows-azure-transport

1. Build the project and run it to verify that it works out of the box
2. Now change the Web settings by right clicking on the azure project and Selecting the "Use IIS Express" option on the web tab.
3. Run the project now

The web role will simply hang. Any ideas? Running under IIS Express is preferred for many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

there seem to be some known issues with IISExpress and Azure. Could you have a look at these pages and see if they help

- [Can't get azure web role to run locally using the emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632041/cant-get-azure-web-role-to-run-locally-using-the-emulator)
- [Workaround for IIS Express Crashing When Running Windows Azure Cloud Service Web Role](http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/05/workaround-for-iis-express-crashing-when-running-windows-azure-cloud-service-web-role-with-multiple-instances-in-windows-azure-sdk-1-8-compute-emulator/)

Comment: if i comment out the nServivceBus bootstrappping code the web role runs just fine configured to run as iisexpress so i am not so sure that it is the IIS Express/Emulator relationship.

Comment: @chutch StackOverflow is not a great place for me to start helping you diagnose this issue. can you please raise a github issue here https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues