# Azure local emulator crashing with no message

Tags: azure

Tying to load up a debug version of my Azure Cloud project it keeps crashing. The problem is with Vs 2012, Azure 2.3. Debugging so far Pressing `Ctrl + Alt + E` to bring up the exceptions window and ticking `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` -> `Thrown` shows the missing file as being'

```
 C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\dftmp\deployment23(1)\config\deployment23(1).CloudParser.WebRole2_IN_0.1.cfg
```

As described in one of the answers [Can't get azure web role to run locally using the emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632041/cant-get-azure-web-role-to-run-locally-using-the-emulator) I've tried deleting the dftmp directory but with no success. Tried running with IE set as the default as well as running in non-debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the VS 2010 SDK and the VS 2012 SDK then reinstalling the VS 2012 SDK fixed this.